# MySQL order alphanumeric column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've been having some unexpected results with a MySQL query. I want to order naturally by the title of my posts (I'm running WordPress but I don't think this is related).

Here's an example of some occurring title to give an idea:

```
1-1-1a
1-13-5j
7-1
9-1-2 
12-13-2a
```

I did quite some research and the closest to the result I wanted I got using

```
ORDER BY (posts.post_title+0) ASC
```

I'm still getting a weird result on one page of results. The full query is as follows.

```
SELECT rlt13_posts.post_title
FROM rlt13_posts
INNER JOIN rlt13_term_relationships ON (rlt13_posts.ID = rlt13_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN rlt13_postmeta ON (rlt13_posts.ID = rlt13_postmeta.post_id)
JOIN rlt13_icl_translations t ON rlt13_posts.ID = t.element_id
AND t.element_type IN ('post_rlt_rule')
JOIN rlt13_icl_languages l ON t.language_code=l.code
AND l.active=1
WHERE 1=1
  AND (rlt13_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (92,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,501))
  AND rlt13_posts.post_type = 'rlt_rule'
  AND (rlt13_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  AND ((rlt13_postmeta.meta_key = 'new_rule'
        AND CAST(rlt13_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = ''))
  AND t.language_code='en'
GROUP BY rlt13_posts.ID
ORDER BY (rlt13_posts.post_title+0) ASC
```

And this query gives the following result after executing (the results out of range are neatly arranged).

[image]

The last two results are kind of baffling to me. The query gives expected results on any other page. I did notice that when I removed the following statement from the query, the 2 unexpected results at the bottom of the previous query would show in the natural order properly.

Any help on getting this thing sorted (literally) is appreciated!

```
AND (rlt13_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (92, ****))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be easy in MySQL since there are difficulties when dealing with delimiter-separated string. As an option, you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function like this (query simplified)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t
ORDER BY
-- left:
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
-- middle:
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
-- right:
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

-also you should not forget about converting type to integer ([CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to `UNSIGNED` in case above). With sample data that would be:

```
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 1-1-1a   |
| 2    | 1-13-5j  |
| 4    | 7-1      |
| 5    | 9-1-2    |
| 3    | 12-13-2a |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I never knew about the SUBSTRING_INDEX function. I was able to solve my issue.